# Keras attribute error due to tensorflow version support in CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm working on a convolutional neural network and I get the error

> AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute
> 'populate_dict_with_module_objects

here is the code excluding the data processing on the dataset.
my version for Keras is 2.4.3, TensorFlow is 2.5.0 and python is 3.8

I've seen many other people facing similar issues but I believe it has to do with compatibility versions of TensorFlow. I have tried like 3-4 versions of TensorFlow but they all gave me obscure errors like the one above.

I hope this can be fixed because otherwise, I don't know how I will continue with the network

```
import pickle 
import time 
import os 
import cv2
import random 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, Activation
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128, input_shape = X.shape[1:]), activation = 'relu')
model.add(Dense(4,activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(X,Y, epochs =2, validation_split = 0.2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) 2.x, you should not mix standalone [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) and new [tf.keras](/questions/tagged/tf.keras) in the same import. You above code should have imported as follows: (test on version 2.4, 2.5 in colab).

```
import pickle, time, os ,cv2, random 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, 
                                     Flatten, Activation)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(4,activation = 'softmax'))
```

Also, note that `input_shape` at the middle of the model doesn't have any effect (as you do in `Dense` layer).